# Reuse one global String instance

Tags: java, variables

Am trying to have just one global String variable that can be used by multiple classes.

Something in `MainActivity` like :

```
public static String sStat = "Starting System...\n";
```

Then I would like other classes to be able to use the same instance of that string (i.e.  append to it, edit it, etc.)

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Of course it is, you already provide the code. Where do you have difficulties using this? Please be more specific. Also, please do not use `\n` as the line separator differs on systems. It's `\r\n` on Windows for example. You can use `System.lineSeparator()` for the correct one. Or use `System.out.println(...)` as opposed to `System.out.print(...)` when printing a line.

Comment: As a note: Your terminology is a bit off. You can not change a `String` instance, as Java `String`s are completely **immutable**. Every method, like appending or editing, creates a new string instead of manipulating the old one. So you need to capture the result in the variable again: `sStat += "hello";`

Comment: Looks like you want to implement some type of message queue which you empty at another location. What about using a `Queue<String>`, adding messages through some `addMessage(String)` method and then displaying them by using `System.out.println(queue.poll())` at your printer location.

Comment: It's possible.  That doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea.  Zabuza's approach sounds better: more testable, etc.

Comment: @Zabuza that's what I'm looking to do.  I just can't figure out how to pass the same string from class to class.

Comment: If you are (still) referring to your original code, you don't pass it.  Both ... in fact all ... classes can access it directly, as `MainActivity.sStat`.  (But as the other comments pointed out, shared mutable static variables are a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a static variable in Java, you must do as following:

***class name + . + variable name***

In your specific case:

```
MainActivity.sStat
```

Note, however, that, as others pointed out, using static mutable variables isn't a good practise.

Comment: I feel stupid.  I was trying to access it outside of a method.  Am that new to Java.

Comment: Don't feel stupid, it's normal to make mistakes when we are beginning (hell, even when are experienced hahah). I'm glad I could help. See ya!!